# Not full binding in knockout

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Knockout doesn't work as expected, im my interface.
I suppose my mistake. But I cannot understand it.

I have an album with genres included tracks with genres:

```
var initialData = [{
    title: 'Danny',
    genres: [
        {id: 21,
        title: 'Noise'},
        {id: 22,
        title: 'EBM'}],
    tracks: [
        {title: 'Pony',
        genres: [
            {id: 21,
            title: 'Noise'},
            {id: 22,
            title: 'EBM'}]},
        {title: 'Hungry',
        genres: [
            {id: 21,
            title: 'Noise'},
            {id: 22,
            title: 'EBM'}]}
    ]

}];
```

I want to create 1-way sync between album genres to tracks genres:

- If i add genre to album, this genre would be added to all tracks.
- If i delete genre from album, this genre would be deleted from all tracks.
- If i add genre to track, this genre would be added only to this track.
- If i delete genre from track, this genre would be deleted only from this track.

My sync works fine (except one case) with this functions:

```
self.addGenre = function(album) {
    var id = rand(),
        item = {
            id: id,
            title: ' genre #' + id
        };
    album.genres.push(item);

    if (album.tracks()) {
        $.each(album.tracks(), function (index, track) {
            track.genres.push(item);
        });
    }
};

self.removeGenre = function(genre) {
    $.each(self.albums(), function() {
        this.genres.remove(genre);
        if (this.tracks()) {
            $.each(this.tracks(), function (index, track) {
                track.genres.remove(genre);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

**Exception is if I want to delete default (Noise, EBM, see initialData above ) genre from albums. it doesn't work.**

**I created an [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/f2E7e/2/) to show this case and include in it a lot of `console.log()` to debug**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you use ko-mapping, it turns every property into an observable. The new genres you create are not the same kind of object as the initial objects, because they are just standard vanilla objects. So the genre you are trying to remove from the track is not the same one you removed from the album.

A simple way to fix your issue is to alter the remove function, as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2E7e/4/).

```
$.each(this.tracks(), function(index, track) {
    var toRemove = ko.utils.arrayFirst(track.genres(), function(item) {
        return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(genre.id) == ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.id);
    });
    track.genres.remove(toRemove);
});
```

A better way would be to be a little more thorough in generating your initial viewmodel, the new genres, or both. This won't be easy.

Comment: I suspected the reason for in ko-mapping, but don't know the solution with `unwrapObservable`. Thank you!